# function not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I am having an error 'saveFilm' was not declared in this scope.
This is made with Qt.
can't figure out why. Please help
here is my code:

```
#ifndef FILM_H
#define FILM_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QDate>

class Film:public QWidget{
public:
    Film(QString t,int dur,QString dir,QDate r);
    Film();
    void setTitle(QString t);
    void setDuration(int dur);
    void setDirector(QString dir);
    void setReleaseDate(QDate r);
    QString getTitle() const;
    int getDuration() const;
    QString getDirector() const;
    QDate getReleaseDate() const;


private:
    QString m_title;
    int m_duration;
    QString m_director;
    QDate m_releaseDate;

};

#endif // FILM_H

#ifndef FILMWRITER_H
#define FILMWRITER_H
#include "Film.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFile>

class FilmWriter: public Film{

public:
    void saveFilm(Film& f);

};
#endif // FILMWRITER_H
#ifndef FILMINPUT_H
#define FILMINPUT_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "Film.h"
#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
    class FilmInput;
}

class FilmInput : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FilmInput(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~FilmInput();
    void obtainFilmData(Film& f);
public slots:
    void getFilm();
private:
    Ui::FilmInput *ui;
    //widgets
    QMainWindow* window;
    QLabel* infoLabel;
    QLabel* titleLabel;
    QLabel* durationLabel;
    QLabel* directorLabel;
    QLabel* relDateLabel;
    QTextEdit* titleEdit;
    QTextEdit* durationEdit;
    QTextEdit* directorEdit;
    QTextEdit* relDateEdit;
    QPushButton* saveBtn;
    QPushButton* cancelBtn;
    Film f;
    //sets up gui and connects signals and slots
    void setUpGui();
};

#endif // FILMINPUT_H
#include "Film.h"
#include <QDate>
#include <QString>

Film::Film(QString t,int dur,QString dir,QDate r):m_title(t),m_duration(dur),m_director(dir),m_releaseDate(r){

}

Film::Film(){
}

void Film::setTitle(QString t){
    m_title = t;
}

void Film::setDuration(int dur){
    m_duration = dur;
}

void Film::setDirector(QString dir){
    m_director = dir;
}

void Film::setReleaseDate(QDate r){
    m_releaseDate = r;
}

QString Film::getTitle() const{
    return QString("%1").arg(m_title);
}

int Film::getDuration() const{
    return m_duration;
}
QString Film::getDirector() const{
    return QString("%1").arg(m_director);
}
QDate Film::getReleaseDate() const{
    return m_releaseDate;
}


#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QObject>

void FilmWriter::saveFilm(Film& f){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,("Save File"));
          if (fileName != "") {
              QFile file(fileName);
              if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
                  QMessageBox::critical(this, ("Error"),("Could not open file"));// error message
              } else {
                  QTextStream stream(&file);
                  stream << f;
                  stream.flush();
                  file.close();
              }
          }

}
#include "filminput.h"
#include "ui_filminput.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include "Film.h"
#include "FilmWriter.h"
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QDate>
#include <QString>

FilmInput::FilmInput(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::FilmInput)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setUpGui();
}

FilmInput::~FilmInput()
{
    delete ui;
}

void FilmInput::setUpGui(){
    //initialise widgets
    infoLabel = new QLabel("Please enter film data which will be saved to a file",this);
    titleLabel = new QLabel("Film Title",this);
    durationLabel = new QLabel("Film Duration",this);
    directorLabel = new QLabel("Film Director",this);
    relDateLabel = new QLabel("Film Release Date",this);
    titleEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    durationEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    directorEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    relDateEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    saveBtn = new QPushButton("Save Film",this);
    cancelBtn = new QPushButton("Cancel",this);
    //set layout
    QFormLayout* layout = new QFormLayout();
    layout->addWidget(infoLabel);
    layout->addWidget(titleLabel);
    layout->addWidget(titleEdit);
    layout->addWidget(durationLabel);
    layout->addWidget(durationEdit);
    layout->addWidget(directorLabel);
    layout->addWidget(directorEdit);
    layout->addWidget(relDateLabel);
    layout->addWidget(relDateEdit);
    layout->addWidget(saveBtn);
    layout->addWidget(cancelBtn);

    this->ui->widget->setLayout(layout);
    this->setWindowTitle("Film Archive");
    connect(saveBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(getFilm()));
    connect(cancelBtn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
}

void FilmInput::getFilm(){
    Film f1(titleEdit->toPlainText(),durationEdit->toPlainText().toInt() ,directorEdit->toPlainText(),
             QDate::fromString(relDateEdit->toPlainText(),"dd/MM/YYYY"));;
    obtainFilmData(f1);
}

void FilmInput::obtainFilmData(Film &f){
    saveFilm(f);
}

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "filminput.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    FilmInput w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The error is in the function void FilmInput::obtainFilmData(Film &f)

near the end.

Comment: Can you split it up file by file? It looks like there are at least 4 different files there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveFilm seems to be member of FilmWriter. For the code to work it needs to be member of FilmInput. Hope it helps. Logically it sounds by the names that a FilmWriter object is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I see no member function of FilmInput, named saveFilm.
On the top it is declared in FilmWriter and there seems to be no link between these two classes.
May this solve your problem?